# Redux Form: Set error to a field without submitting the form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a form that is loading data from an API. I'm trying to set manually an error to the field if occurs some error in the api call.

```
// This is the input that I'm trying to set the error message
<Field
   name="username"
   component={CustomCombobox}
 />
```

Here I'm trying to set an error in the catch block.

```
try {
   const { data } = await UserService.getUser();
  } catch (e) {
     // here I'm trying to set an error to "username" field
     stopSubmit('myFormName', { username: 'Something wrong happened.' })
}
```

But here's is the problem. I'm not submitting the form, so the stopSubmit does not work. I'm just receiving data from an API to fill the options, and if some error happens I want to set the error manually.

Answer (score -1):

[This website has some examples on form validation](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/)
If you are trying to run a check on the username before submitting the form, you could run an API call on the value of the field and then show the error if the function fails.

Maybe this isn't what you are looking for / I have misunderstood

Comment: I'm not trying to submit the form. I just want to set an error to the field when the try block fails. Btw, I'm using try catch block.

Comment: In the link provided they are able to create a new div / label to show an error message / warning, could you not use something similar?